# All music gone in iTunes version 12.4.0.119 after upgrade

Tags: itunes, software-update, windows

All of my music in iTunes is gone.

I upgrade to version 12.4.0.119 from the previous version.

After I rebooted all of the music and custom playlists are gone in iTunes.

All of the media files are available on my hard drive and iTunes is pointed at this folder.

***Is there an .xml file that I may need to move to another directory in order for iTunes to look in the appropriate place to 'see' the music and playlist files/db?***

- I am running Windows 7 64-bit on this machine.
- I have no other issues with other applications.
- My event log is clean.
- I synch iTunes to an iPhone 5S.
- All of my music and playlists on the phone are not affected by the issue as far as I can see.

I can't find anything of value on the Internet regarding this issue.  Perhaps I am using the wrong search parameters.

TIA

Comment: iTunes Library.itl and iTunes Music Library.xml are critical. Make sure that they're good.

Comment: That's what I am asking about.  I mentioned the xml files.   How can I tell iTunes to use the correct ones?  What are the correct ones?  What is the path to correct ones?

Comment: It simply uses whatever one is in your iTunes folder (C:\Users\username\My Music\iTunes\). The correct ones would be generated by iTunes in the past–perhaps if you have a backup, use one of them.

Comment: btw, don't attempt to sync the phone until you get this fixed. If your iTunes Library file appears to be in the right place, by default as @JMY1000 says, & it's still not picking it up, try launching iTunes holding Shift & it will ask you to find the library manually. Assuming the lib itself is still OK, this ought to fix the association.